# Как дождаться загрузки картинки на чужой странице?

Tags: javascript

В *IE*, вроде бы, у картинки есть свойство `readyState`. Мне нужно для *Firefox*.

`onLoad` не срабатывает, т.к. его нужно успеть установить до начала загрузки.

`document.readyState` опять же не подходит, т. к. картинка создается с помощью *JS* после загрузки страницы.

Появление элемента легко отслеживается, но на выходе получаю заглушку.

Можно, конечно, сделать небольшую задержку, но это некрасиво, да и спасет не всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onLoad не работает, c jQuery $(img).bind('load'... работает только если установить событие до окночания загрузки картинки.

Оказалось, что у IMG есть специальные свойства: `complete, naturalHeight/Width`. Единственное, они не работают с анимированными GIF. Проверял только в Firefox